# Just Audio implementation of duration and seeker

Tags: flutter, duration, just-audio

Am working on an Audio player app in flutter, am really a starter i would like to implement a seeker and duration feature on my app and am failing. I would like to get the duration of the song am playing and let user know how long they have played the song as well to allow them to seek. Will you please guys help.
Bellow is my code.

```
import 'package:app/shared/MusicProgressIndicator.dart';
import 'package:app/screens/SingleSongScreen.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class SingleSongScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "SingleSongScreen";
  static var song = {};
  SingleSongScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SingleSongScreenState createState() => _SingleSongScreenState();
}

class _SingleSongScreenState extends State<SingleSongScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Duration currentDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 1000);
  bool showRemaining = false;
  AnimationController controller;
  final player  = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    )..addListener(() {
        setState(() {});
      });
    controller.repeat(reverse: true);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    player.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var song      = SingleSongScreen.song;
    var songPath  = "";
    songPath      = app.base+"play.php?file="+song['song'];
    print(song);
    print(songPath);

    player.setUrl(songPath);

    return Window(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      header: Container(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            IconicButton(
              icon: backIcon,
              iconColor: Colors.grey,
              transparent: true,
              circledIcon: false,
              size: 40,
              onClicked: () {
                goBack(context);
              },
            ),
            Favicon(onClicked: () {
              goto(page: MainScreen.id, context: context);
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: [
        VerticalSpacer(
          h: 20,
        ),
        Container(
          height: 250,
          child: Carousel(
            boxFit: BoxFit.contain,
            autoplay: carouselAutoPlay,
            animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
            dotSize: 6.0,
            dotIncreasedColor: Color(0xFF33A3FF),
            dotBgColor: Colors.transparent,
            dotPosition: DotPosition.bottomCenter,
            dotVerticalPadding: 10.0,
            showIndicator: true,
            indicatorBgPadding: 7.0,
            images: images(),
          ),
        )
      ],
      footer: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              child: Marquee(
                child: Label(
                  song['title'],
                  bold: true,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              child: Marquee(
                child: Label(
                  song['artist'],
                  bold: true,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
            ),

            // ACTION ICONS SECTION
            VerticalSpacer(
              h: 25,
            ),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  VerticalIconicButton(
                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.fileDownload,
                    label: "Download",
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                    scale: 1.2,
                    onClicked: (){

                    });
                    },
                  ),
                  VerticalIconicButton(
                    icon: Icons.favorite_border_outlined,
                    label: "Favourite",
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                    scale: 1.2,
                  ),
                  VerticalIconicButton(
                    icon: FontAwesomeIcons.readme,
                    label: "Lyrics",
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    textColor: Colors.grey,
                    scale: 1.2,
                    onClicked: () {
                    
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // SONG PLAY PROGRESS INDICATOR
            VerticalSpacer(),
            MusicProgressIndicator(
              progress: currentDuration,
              buffered: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
              total: Duration(milliseconds: 5000),
              showTotalRemainingTime: showRemaining,
              onSeek: (duration) {
                setState(() {
                  currentDuration = duration;
                  showRemaining = !showRemaining;
                });
                 player.seek(duration);
              },
            ),

            // MUSIC PLAY CONTROLLER ACTION BUTTON
            VerticalSpacer(
              h: 20,
            ),

            Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  IconicButton(
                    icon: Icons.repeat_one,
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    transparent: true,
                    circledIcon: false,
                    size: 50,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconicButton(
                              icon: Icons.skip_previous_rounded,
                              iconColor: Colors.white,
                              transparent: true,
                              circledIcon: false,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 15),
                        IconicButton(
                          icon: Icons.play_circle_filled,
                          iconColor: Colors.grey,
                          iconCircleColor: Colors.blue,
                          size: 50,
                          onClicked: (){
                            //player.stop();
                            player.play();
                            currentDuration=player.position;
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 15,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: IconicButton(
                              icon: Icons.skip_next_rounded,
                              iconColor: Colors.white,
                              transparent: true,
                              circledIcon: false,
                              size: 50,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconicButton(
                    icon: Icons.queue_music_outlined,
                    iconColor: Colors.grey,
                    transparent: true,
                    circledIcon: false,
                    size: 50,
                    onClicked: () {
                      goto(page: AllSongsScreen.id, context: context);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // BOTTTOM SPACE
            VerticalSpacer(
              h: 30,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void toast(String message){
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content:  Text(message.toString()),
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: 'OK',
        onPressed: () { },
      ),
    )
    );
  }
}
```

MusicProgressIndicator.dart

```
import 'package:audio_video_progress_bar/audio_video_progress_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MusicProgressIndicator extends StatelessWidget {
  Duration progress, buffered, total;
  Function onSeek;
  bool showTotalRemainingTime, minified, showTime;
  MusicProgressIndicator({
    Key key,
    this.buffered,
    @required this.onSeek,
    @required this.progress,
    @required this.total,
    this.showTotalRemainingTime: false,
    this.showTime: true,
    this.minified: false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ProgressBar(
      progress: progress,
      buffered: buffered,
      total: total,
      progressBarColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
      baseBarColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24),
      bufferedBarColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.24),
      timeLabelLocation:
          showTime ? TimeLabelLocation.sides : TimeLabelLocation.none,
      timeLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      timeLabelType: showTotalRemainingTime
          ? TimeLabelType.remainingTime
          : TimeLabelType.totalTime,
      thumbColor: Colors.white,
      barHeight: minified ? 2.0 : 5.0,
      thumbRadius: minified ? 1.0 : 5.0,
      onSeek: (duration) {
        onSeek(duration);
        print('User selected a new time: $duration');
       
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There's a lot in your question that makes it difficult to answer, and I think you would be better to ask some narrower questions. 1) Your build function should only build the widget, it should not perform business logic such as telling the player to load audio. This will reload audio each time the widget tree is rebuilt. 2) You didn't include the source for the MusicProgressIndicator which I think is part of your question. 3) The just_audio example already demonstrates how to do what you're trying to do, so you'd be better off starting there and then asking about what you don't understand.

Comment: I have added MusicProgressIndicator.dart, to be honest i have tried just_audio example but marrying my code with the example is what seem to be the problem kindly help a bro.